# How to join jsonb array elements in Postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am using Postgres 9.5, and I have the following tables:

**Users**

- id UUID
- name TEXT

**Images**

- id UUID
- key TEXT
- width INTEGER
- height INTEGER

**Posts**

- id UUID
- title TEXT
- author_id UUID
- content JSONB

The posts' content is like:

```
[
  { "type": "text", "text": "learning pg" },
  { "type": "image", "image_id": "8f4422b4-3936-49f5-ab02-50aea5e6755f" },
  { "type": "image", "image_id": "57efc97c-b9b4-4cd5-b1e1-3539f5853835" },
  { "type": "text", "text": "pg is awesome" }
]
```

Now I want to join the image type of content, and populate them with `image_id`, like:

```
{
  "id": "cb1267ca-b1ac-4daa-8c7e-72d4c000e9fa",
  "title": "Learning join jsonb in Postgres",
  "author_id": "deba01b7-ec58-4cc2-b3ae-7dc42e582767",
  "content": [
    { "type": "text", "text": "learning pg" },
    {
       "type": "image",
       "image": {
         "id": "8f4422b4-3936-49f5-ab02-50aea5e6755f",
         "key": "/upload/test1.jpg",
         "width": 800,
         "height": 600
       }
    },
    {
       "type": "image",
       "image": {
         "id": "57efc97c-b9b4-4cd5-b1e1-3539f5853835",
         "key": "/upload/test2.jpg",
         "width": 1280,
         "height": 720
       }
    },
    { "type": "text", "text": "pg is awesome" }
  ]
}
```

Here is my test sql file:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Images;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Posts;

CREATE TABLE Users (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Images (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  key TEXT,
  width INTEGER,
  height INTEGER,
  creator_id UUID
);

CREATE TABLE Posts (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  title TEXT,
  author_id UUID,
  content JSONB
);


DO $$
DECLARE user_id UUID;
DECLARE image1_id UUID;
DECLARE image2_id UUID;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Users (name) VALUES ('test user') RETURNING id INTO user_id;
INSERT INTO Images (key, width, height, creator_id) VALUES ('upload/test1.jpg', 800, 600, user_id) RETURNING id INTO image1_id;
INSERT INTO Images (key, width, height, creator_id) VALUES ('upload/test2.jpg', 600, 400, user_id) RETURNING id INTO image2_id;
INSERT INTO Posts (title, author_id, content) VALUES (
  'test post',
  user_id,
  ('[ { "type": "text", "text": "learning pg" }, { "type": "image", "image_id": "' || image1_id || '" }, { "type": "image", "image_id": "' || image2_id || '" }, { "type": "text", "text": "pg is awesome" } ]') :: JSONB
);

END $$;
```

Is there any way to implement this requirement?

Comment: It would be more useful if you posted actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) which we can use to reproduce the case instead of the pseudo code. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for you suggestion, I've add the sql statements to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```sql
SELECT jsonb_pretty(to_jsonb(p)) AS post_row_as_json
FROM  (
   SELECT id, title, author_id, c.content
   FROM   posts p
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT jsonb_agg(
               CASE WHEN c.elem->>'type' = 'image' AND i.id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN elem - 'image_id' || jsonb_build_object('image', i)
                    ELSE c.elem END) AS content
      FROM   jsonb_array_elements(p.content) AS c(elem)
      LEFT   JOIN images i ON c.elem->>'type' = 'image'
                          AND i.id = (elem->>'image_id')::uuid
      ) c ON true
   ) p;
```

#### How?

1. Unnest the `jsonb` array, producing 1 row per array element:

   ```
   jsonb_array_elements(p.content) AS c(elem)
   ```
2. For each element `LEFT JOIN` to `images` on the conditions that

   - ... the *key* 'type' has the *value* 'image': `c.elem->>'type' = 'image'`
   - ... the UUID in `image_id` matches: `i.id = (elem->>'image_id')::uuid`
     An invalid UUID in `content` would raise an exception.
3. For image types, where a matching image was found

   ```
   c.elem->>'type' = 'image' AND i.id IS NOT NULL
   ```

   remove the key 'image_id' and add the related image row as `jsonb` value:

   ```
   elem - 'image_id' || jsonb_build_object('image', i)
   ```

   Else keep the original element.
4. Re-aggregate the modified elements to a new `content` column with `jsonb_agg()`.
   Would work with a plain [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) as well.
5. Unconditionally `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` the result to `posts` and select all columns, only replace `p.content` with the generated replacement `c.content`
6. In the outer `SELECT`, convert the whole row to `jsonb` with a simple `to_jsonb()`.
   `jsonb_pretty()` is only for human-readable representation and totally optional.

All `jsonb` functions are documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Comment: Big up for calling out the usage of `jsonb_array_elements` - it helped me find a solution to our only-slightly-related problem