# Nesting json_agg() inside json_agg()

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have these 2 tables tasks and subtasks with these columns:

```
Tasks
id
name
description
Subtasks
id
name
description
task_id
```

I'm trying to do a query that would output something like this:

```
[
{
id:30,
name:"Do something",
description:"Do this",
  sub_task:[
    {id:1,name:"test",description:"test"}
  ]
}
]
```

After some research I found out how to query data as json and it works if I don't have something nested, and I can't figure out how to do it.
This is what I tried:

```
let query =
      "SELECT t.id, json_agg(json_build_object('name',t.name,'description',t.description,'id',t.id,'subtask',json_agg(json_builder_object('name',s.name,'description',s.description)))) as test from task t ";
    query += " inner join subtask s on s.task_id = t.id ";
```

I tried to do this nested `json_agg()` but I get this error:

```
json_builder_object(unknown, character varying, unknown, text) does not exist
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's [`json_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE), not <strike>`json_builder_object()`</strike>.

But the main issue is that you cannot nest aggregate functions. You need a subquery or a CTE for that. Like:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id',t.id, 'name',t.name, 'description',t.description, 'subtask',s.sub_task)) AS task
FROM   tasks t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id',s.id, 'name',s.name, 'description',s.description)) AS sub_task
   FROM   subtasks s
   WHERE  task_id = t.id
   ) s;
```

Or equivalent:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(t) AS tasks
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tasks t
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT json_agg(sub_task) AS sub_task
      FROM  (
         SELECT id, name, description
         FROM   subtasks
         WHERE  task_id = t.id
         ) sub_task
      ) s
   ) t;
```

Related:

- [How to join nested jsonb array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275606/how-to-join-nested-jsonb-array-elements/47366455#47366455)
- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter!

Comment: Very helpful and revealing. Thanks for posting.